# Delete a row from table in Android Application comparing other table

Tags: java, android, database

I have two table A and B

```
A has aid, bid, aname columns
B has bid, bname columns
```

I want to delete a row from A

i.e `delete from A where bid = (select bid from b where bname like '%Mass%' )`

how can I write Query in Android.

one thing I can do execute `select bid from b where bname like '%Mass%'` separately and store id in a variable and run delete method of class database.

Is there any other easy way.

Comment: I think you can use [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM A WHERE bid IN (SELECT bid FROM B WHERE bname LIKE '%Mass%')
```